# How to run many TensorFlow instances in parallel on different GPUs on the same machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Let's pretend that I launch the following commands in parallel to train many TensorFlow models at once on the same machine:

- `python3 launch_training.py --gpu 0`
- `python3 launch_training.py --gpu 1`
- `python3 launch_training.py --gpu 2`
- `python3 launch_training.py --gpu 3`
- `python3 launch_training.py --gpu 4`
- `python3 launch_training.py --gpu 5`
- `python3 launch_training.py --gpu 6`
- `python3 launch_training.py --gpu 7`

Let's pretend that inside `launch_training.py`, a TensorFlow graph and session are created, and with the following context: `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):`, and where the `0` is replaced by the proper `--gpu` index argument).

Will this work? If not, which steps would I have to take to make this work? I'd like to know this before renting GPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify a gpu device with `with tf.device('gpu:N')` where `N` is the device index.  Read https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu and https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/116 first

I think you've confused running the same script multiple times on different GPUs and running one script using multiple GPUs. In the former case, read the "Using a single GPU on a multi-GPU system" section of the TensorFlow guide, for the latter "Using multiple GPUs".

Comment: Oops, let me change `with tf.device('/cpu:0'):` to `with tf.device('/gpu:N'):` in my question. I'm indeed using GPU. My concerns are wider than this line of code. It's about wheter or not the code will work in parallel with greater considerations. With that in mind, your answer is not useful, but thanks for letting me notice the typo.

Comment: I cannot say anything more than "it should theoretically work" without seeing the code

Comment: I don't honestly see how it could allocate all GPUs at once when you explicitly specify on which device it should run

Comment: For example: will the first call to the script (like this: python3 launch_training.py --gpu 0) hog the memory of all the GPUs at once, making the second script not-runnable in parallel?

Comment: No, when you specify the device, the code will run only on this device, ergo will only use this device's memory. If you want the code to run on multiple GPUs then read "Using multiple GPUs" section of the Tensorflow guide

Comment: Thank you ! That really helped me, i used with  `tf.device('/CPU:0'):` since the GPU has higher priority to be used than GPU